Is it possible to connect any point $a$ to a global minimum $b$ for $f$ with a path $\gamma$ such that $f\circ\gamma$ is non-increasing?
I am doing some research on PDE theory, and in order to prove a problem I'm working on, I had an idea, and this idear relates to the following problem
Let $E$ be a Banach space and $f:E\to\mathbb{R}$ a $C^1$ function. Suppose that if $x_n$ is a sequence that $\|x_n\|\to\infty$, then $f(x_n)\to\infty$ ($f$ is coercive). Moreover, suppose that $f$ has one, and only one global minimum $b$, and it has no local minima other than $b$. So what I'm struggling to prove is: given any point $a\neq b$, is there a continuous path $\gamma:[0,1]\to E$ with $\gamma(0)=a$ and $\gamma(1)=b$ such that $f\circ \gamma$ is non-increasing?
The first idea I had to show a possible existence was to work locally first. For example let $B_\delta(a)$ be the open ball of radius $\delta$ and center $a$, is there a continuous path connecting $a$ with a point on $\partial B_\delta(a)$ such that the composition of $f$ with this path is non-increasing? After proving that, try to connect all those paths until we reach $b$.
Do you have any thoughts on that? I would not be surprised if it were false though. When $f$ is not coercive it is clearly not true.

"$||x_n||→∞$" ?

@SamGinrich Yeah, that is the definition of $x_n\to\infty$. But I will make it clear anyways.

You should try to use the fact that you assume there are no local minima; this is a strong assumption.

@JürgenSukumaran Yeah it is. It implies that for any point $a\neq b$ there exists a direction on $a$ in which it is non-increasing, so we can descend a little bit. However i guess there might be the possibility when we descend infinitely many times but we converge to a point different from $b$. So this is not that simple as it might seem

@JürgenSukumaran. Also it obviously implies that for any ball $B_\delta(a)$ there exists $y$ in such a ball such that $f(y)<f(a)$. But how connect $a$ with $y$ with a non-increasing continuous path?

Something like this might serve as counter example https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3465677/1001541

@SamGinrich I'm not sure how that example relates to my problem...
